# Spock- Capture method arguments in private method call of class under test

Tags: groovy, spock

I am trying to test my Service class below

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class TaskTemplateService {
  @NonNull
  TaskTemplateRepository taskTemplateRepository;

  public void doStuff() {
    List<MyObject> list;
    doOtherStuff(list)
  }

  private void doOtherStuff(List <MyObject>) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

When I am testing the real TaskTemplate, how can I capture what is passed to doOtherStuff?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and why would you?

Good testing means to specify the behaviour of a unit's public interface. Private methods ought to be covered via testing this way indirectly. If this is not possible then either you have dead, unreachable code or a design problem and should refactor.

BTW, the technical reason that you cannot mock/stub private methods is that most mocking tools, also the built-in feature of Spock, use dynamic proxies (DP) in order to implement mocking. DP technically are subclasses, but private methods can never be extended or even seen by subclasses or being called by them or from other classes, hence the term "private". Consequently, a mock subclass cannot check interactions with private methods.

How exactly you ought to redesign your class in order to make it testable really depends on why you want to "capture" the method argument, as you say. Do you need to replace it by a mock? Do you need to modify or verify the content of the original object?

- If the object has a central meaning and you need to replace or verify it, why not make it injectable instead of creating it as a local variable, hermetically sealing it off from the outside world and making it untestable?
- Or maybe in your case you could make the private method protected or package-scoped in order to make it testable. Then at least a mock could be created for it and you could capture the argument or stub the result.

I am mostly speculating here because the answer really depends on what is behind `//do stuff`, i.e. the very information you are hiding in your sample code.